# [[!getFrontendRequests?]] в HTML коде (мб jQuery/AJAX/js)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Получил наследство в виде сайта, где требуется удалить пару постов, а посты подтягиваются непонятно откуда. В коде на месте, куда вставляются div'ы такой код:

```html
<div class="posts">
  [[!getFrontendRequests?]]
</div>
```

Перерыл интернет, ничего похожего не нашёл. Что это за вызов?

Answer (score 2):

Это сниппет(php код который в вашем случаи выводит html) в modx под названием getFrontendRequests 
http://realadmin.ru/saytostroy/basic-concepts-modx.html

его можна найти примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]